# React Native: error: cannot find symbol > new AppCenterReactNativeAnalyticsPackage(MainApplication.this

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

I was getting a successful build with `android` in React Native until I added these:

```
"appcenter-analytics": "2.1.0",
    "appcenter-crashes": "2.1.0",
```

I am on:

```
"react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.4",
```

The error is:

> Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug
>   -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 Note: /Users/danale/Projects/NFIBEngage/node_modules/react-native-sentry/android/src/main/java/io/sentry/RNSentryModule.java
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for
>   details.
>   /Users/danale/Projects/NFIBEngage/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:60:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>         new AppCenterReactNativeAnalyticsPackage(MainApplication.this, getResources().getString(R.string.appCenterAnalytics_whenToEnableAnalytics)),
>                                                  ^   symbol:   class MainApplication   location: class PackageList
>   /Users/danale/Projects/NFIBEngage/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:60:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>         new AppCenterReactNativeAnalyticsPackage(MainApplication.this, getResources().getString(R.string.appCenterAnalytics_whenToEnableAnalytics)),
>                                                                                                         ^   symbol:   variable appCenterAnalytics_whenToEnableAnalytics
>   location: class string
>   /Users/danale/Projects/NFIBEngage/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:61:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>         new AppCenterReactNativeCrashesPackage(MainApplication.this, getResources().getString(R.string.appCenterCrashes_whenToSendCrashes)),
>                                                ^   symbol:   class MainApplication   location: class PackageList
>   /Users/danale/Projects/NFIBEngage/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:61:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>         new AppCenterReactNativeCrashesPackage(MainApplication.this, getResources().getString(R.string.appCenterCrashes_whenToSendCrashes)),
>                                                                                                       ^   symbol:   variable appCenterCrashes_whenToSendCrashes   location:
>   class string 4 errors
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Apparently there is this `android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java` file that did not exist with the legacy version of this application:

```
package com.facebook.react;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.nfibengage.BuildConfig;
import com.nfibengage.R;

// @react-native-community/async-storage
import com.reactnativecommunity.asyncstorage.AsyncStoragePackage;
// appcenter-analytics
import com.microsoft.appcenter.reactnative.analytics.AppCenterReactNativeAnalyticsPackage;
// appcenter-crashes
import com.microsoft.appcenter.reactnative.crashes.AppCenterReactNativeCrashesPackage;
// react-native-sentry
import io.sentry.RNSentryPackage;
// react-native-splash-screen
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;

public class PackageList {
  private Application application;
  private ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost;
  public PackageList(ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost) {
    this.reactNativeHost = reactNativeHost;
  }

  public PackageList(Application application) {
    this.reactNativeHost = null;
    this.application = application;
  }

  private ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return this.reactNativeHost;
  }

  private Resources getResources() {
    return this.getApplication().getResources();
  }

  private Application getApplication() {
    if (this.reactNativeHost == null) return this.application;
    return this.reactNativeHost.getApplication();
  }

  private Context getApplicationContext() {
    return this.getApplication().getApplicationContext();
  }

  public ArrayList<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new AsyncStoragePackage(),
      new AppCenterReactNativeAnalyticsPackage(MainApplication.this, getResources().getString(R.string.appCenterAnalytics_whenToEnableAnalytics)),
      new AppCenterReactNativeCrashesPackage(MainApplication.this, getResources().getString(R.string.appCenterCrashes_whenToSendCrashes)),
      new RNSentryPackage(),
      new SplashScreenReactPackage()
    ));
  }
}
```

The `MainApplication.java` file is inside of `android/main/java/com/nfibengage/MainApplication.java`:

```
package com.nfibengage;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutorFactory;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptExecutorFactory;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

I tried importing it into `PackageList.java` like so:

```
import com.nfibengage.MainApplication;
```

but I continue to get the same error. If anyone can walk me through where did this `PackageList.java` file come from and how do I get this working again short of just completely removing `appcenter-analytics` and `appcenter-crashes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure your installation order is the same as the following.

**Add the App Center SDK modules**

```
npm install appcenter appcenter-analytics appcenter-crashes --save-exact
```

or

```
yarn add appcenter appcenter-analytics appcenter-crashes --exact
```

**Integrate the SDK automatically**

```
react-native link appcenter
react-native link appcenter-analytics
react-native link appcenter-crashes
```

App Center SDK does not set up mocks automatically for App Center modules during the linking process. If you are using **Jest test framework** in your application and experience errors caused by the App Center SDK while running tests with **Jest**, add the following to the jest section of `package.json` file (include only modules in use):

```
"setupFiles": [
   "<rootDir>/node_modules/appcenter/test/AppCenterMock.js",
   "<rootDir>/node_modules/appcenter-analytics/test/AppCenterAnalyticsMock.js",
   "<rootDir>/node_modules/appcenter-crashes/test/AppCenterCrashesMock.js",
   "<rootDir>/node_modules/appcenter-push/test/AppCenterPushMock.js"
]
```

Edit the project's `android/app/src/main/assets/appcenter-config.json` and replace the `YOUR_APP_SECRET` placeholder value with your App Center project's application secret.

Comment: I got this error when following your steps `[!] No podspec found for `appcenter-crashes` in `../node_modules/appcenter-crashes``, everything else worked fine. What does this mean?

Comment: I don't think there is a `podsec` file for `appcenter-crashes`. If you do not have a file in the direct path, please create and add the `podsec` file yourself.

Answer (score 0):

do one think only

1. goto your folder structure.
   2.Add a file yarn-error.log

there will not be any problem your project will start well.